# I want to replace two separate words with only one word in PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to replace two words in a sentence with one word, like in the following example:

> Kippa's **luck** was very **bad** yesterday.

I want to change it to:

> Kippa's was very **misfortune** yesterday.

In this example, I know it has no sense, but it's just an example,
I want to replace (luck & bad) with the word (misfortune) in php.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arrays as parameters to `str_replace`

```
<?php
     $youText  = "Kippa's luck was very bad yesterday.";
     $replace_1 = ["bad", "luck"];
     $replace_2 = ["misfortune", ""];

     $result = str_replace($replace_1, $replace_2, $youText);
     echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!
But I have a very long text with more than one replacement like that one with different strings. How could I make that with a lot of words?

Comment: all string set in segment who you want to change. like `$replace_1= ["bad", "luck","other.."]` and set segment 2 is `$replace_1 = ["misfortune", "misfortune", "misfortune"]`

Comment: Thank you. but actually there are alot of different words to be changed with, not only one word. I need something like this: **

$URLContent = "he has a bad luck. but he is ok, a good man";

     $remove_multi = array(['bad', 'luck'],
         ['good', 'man']);
       
     $replace_multi = array(['misfortune', ''],
       ['nice', '']);


$URLContent = str_replace($remove_multi, $replace_multi, $URLContent); **

Answer (score -1):

Thank you. but actually there are alot of different words to be changed with, not only one word. I need something like this: **

```
$URLContent = "he has a bad luck. but he is ok, a good man";

     $remove_multi = array(['bad', 'luck'],
                           ['good', 'man']);
                            
     $replace_multi = array(['misfortune', ''],
                            ['nice', '']);


$URLContent = str_replace($remove_multi, $replace_multi, $URLContent);
```

Comment: Could anyone help me with this?